# IE11 stuck at initial start page for webdriver server only when connection to the URL is slow

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, internet-explorer-11

For the IE webdriver, it opens the IE browsers but it starts to load the local host and then stops (ie/ It never stated loading ). WHen the browser stops loading it shows the msg 'Initial start page for webdriver server'. The problem is that this does not occur every time I execute the test case making it difficult to identify what could be the cause of the issue. What I have noticed is when this issue occurs, the url will take ~25 secs to load manually on the same machine. When the issue does not occur, the URL will load within 3secs.

All security setting are the same (protected Mode enabled across all zone)

enhance protected mode is disabled

IE version 11

the URL is added as a trusted site.

Any clue why it does not load the URL sometimes?

Comment: Have you made sure the zoom level? And, also is it possible to share the code that instantiate the driver?

Comment: yes zoom is at 100%

self.driver = webdriver.Ie()
self.driver.set_page_load_timeout(30)
self.driver.get(URL)

Comment: Does it finally error out?

Comment: Actually it doesn't, it thinks the step passed and move on to interacting with the elements. For some reason some of the element interaction passes as well and some fail

Comment: What is interesting, is even though the page didn't render, part of the automated test case was able to execute. ie/ links were being click and popups were being generated. But when I click F12 on the initial start page browser there are no html. Its like the aut is there but not really there :(

Also the `driver.quit()` does not close the browser. Looks like it lost the connection to the browser

Answer (score 1):

I would try with disabling *IE Native event*. And, sorry that I cannot provide you the `Python` syntax right a way. The following is `C#` which should be fairly easy to convert.

```
var ieOptions = new InternetExplorerOptions 
{ EnableNativeEvents = false };
ieOptions.EnsureCleanSession = true;  
driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(ieOptions);
```

Comment: unfortunately that didn't do the trick :(. Thanks for you help anyways

Answer (score 0):

Use remote driver with desired cap (pageLoadStrategy)

Release notes from seleniumhq.org. Note that we have to use version 2.46 for the jar, iedriverserver.exe and python client driver in order to have things work correctly. It is unclear why 2.45 does not work given the release notes below.

## v2.45.0.2

- Updates to JavaScript automation atoms.
- Added pageLoadStrategy to IE driver. Setting a capability named 
  pageLoadStrategy when creating a session with the IE driver will now change
  the wait behavior when navigating to a new page. The valid values are:

  "normal" - Waits for document.readyState to be 'complete'. This is the
              default, and is the same behavior as all previous versions of
              the IE driver.

  "eager"  - Will abort the wait when document.readyState is
              'interactive' instead of waiting for 'complete'.

  "none"   - Will abort the wait immediately, without waiting for any of
              the page to load.

Setting the capability to an invalid value will result in use of the
   "normal" page load strategy.

Answer (score 0):

It hasn't been updated for a while, but recently I had very similar issue - IEDriverServer was eventually opening page under test, but in most cases just stuck on Initial page of WebDriver.

What I found the root cause (in my case) was startup setting of IE. I had ***Start with tabs from the last session*** enabled, when changed back to ***Start with home page*** driver started to work like a charm, opening page under test in 100% of tries.